# SpringBoot Repository Test Authenticate Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I implemented Authentication system to my Product backend side. It has been working since I had built it. Then I added Refresh token and Role system to project and they also worked perfectly but When I wanna build Repository Test Unit, Intellij says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@64d1f549 testClass = hakan.productData.repository.ProductRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [hakan.productData.ProductDataApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@1fb61db4 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@50029372, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@6cc4cdb9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@3b29d8df, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@4bff7da0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@c72389f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6dd7b5a3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a15ca993], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119) ~[spring-test-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "hakan.productData.business.responses.AuthenticationResponse.getToken()" because the return value of "hakan.productData.business.jwt.AuthenticationService.register(hakan.productData.business.requests.RegisterRequest)" is null
    at hakan.productData.ProductDataApplication.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(ProductDataApplication.java:88) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

AuthenticationService =

```
package hakan.productData.business.jwt;

import hakan.productData.business.requests.AuthenticationRequest;
import hakan.productData.business.requests.RegisterRequest;
import hakan.productData.business.responses.AuthenticationResponse;
import hakan.productData.dataAccess.abstracts.UserRepository;
import hakan.productData.entities.concretes.Role;
import hakan.productData.entities.concretes.User;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private  final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JWTService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
      var user = User.builder()
              .firstName(registerRequest.getFirstName())
              .lastName(registerRequest.getLastName())
              .email(registerRequest.getEmail())
              .password(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()))
              .role(registerRequest.getRole())
              .build();
      userRepository.save(user);
      var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user.getEmail());
      return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
              .token(jwtToken)
              .build();

    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest registerRequest) {
    authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    registerRequest.getEmail(),
                    registerRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );
    var user =userRepository.findByEmail(registerRequest.getEmail())
            .orElseThrow();
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user.getEmail());
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .token(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Repository Test =

```
package hakan.productData.repository;

import hakan.productData.business.jwt.AuthenticationService;
import hakan.productData.business.requests.AuthenticationRequest;
import hakan.productData.business.requests.RegisterRequest;
import hakan.productData.dataAccess.abstracts.ProductRepository;
import hakan.productData.entities.concretes.Product;
import hakan.productData.entities.concretes.RefreshToken;
import hakan.productData.entities.concretes.Role;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProductRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = RegisterRequest.builder()
                .firstName("Admin")
                .lastName("Admin")
                .email("admin@mail.com")
                .password("admin")
                .role(Role.ADMIN)
                .build();
        authenticationService.register(registerRequest);
        AuthenticationRequest authenticate = AuthenticationRequest.builder()
                .email(registerRequest.getEmail())
                .password(registerRequest.getPassword()).build();

        authenticationService.authenticate(authenticate);

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should Save Post")
    public void shouldSavePost() {
        Product product = Product.builder()
                .name("Milk")
                .category("Drink")
                .price(10)
                .quantity(10)
                .onOffer(true)
                .build();
        Product actualProductObject = productRepository.save(product);
        assertThat(actualProductObject).usingRecursiveComparison()
                .ignoringFields("id").isEqualTo(product);

    }

}
```

I can not solve even if I added @Before annotation.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You shouldn't use MockitoExtension if you are running a Spring Boot test

Comment: Even if I delete that, my test gives error again.